# Removing and copying XML elements with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

With XSLT, I'd like to transform an XML file that has the following structure:

```
<e1>
  <e2 a="a1" b="b1" c="c1">
    <e3 foo="a"/>
    <e3 foo="b"/>
    <e3 foo="c"/>
    ...
  </e2>
  <e2 a="a2" b="b2" c="c2">
    <e3 foo="d"/>
    ...
  </e2>
  ...
</e1>
```

Into:

```
<e1>
  <e2 a="a1" b="b1" c="c1">
    <e3 a="a1" b="b1" e="e"/>
  </e2>
  <e2 a="a2" b="b2" c="c2">
    <e3 a="a2" b="b2" e="e"/>
  </e2>
  ...
</e1>
```

In words: I need to remove e3 elements completely, and substitute them with a copy of the enclosing e2 element, with its name changed to e3; copying some of the attributes (e.g. a, b) to the new element, and adding some new attributes (e.g. e).

Anything else must stay intact.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. **1.** What do you mean by _substitute them with a copy of the enclosing e2 element, with its name changed to e3_, because I can still see both `e2` and `e3` elements in your output. **2.** Please be specific about the attributes to be copied and not letting us assume something.

Comment: @LingamurthyCS, the new e3 element is a copy of the enclosing e2 element with some attributes removed, and some added.  Attributes to be copied - as in the example a and b, c is removed, e is added.

Comment: Which attributes do you want removed and which do you want to add?

Comment: @LingamurthyCS, I've edited the previous comment. a and b are copied, c is removed, e is added.

Comment: "*e is added*". With a value coming from ...?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, the value of e is hard-coded. In this case it's "e"

Comment: @malenkiy_scot Can `e2` elements have child elements? If yes, how do you want them processed?

Comment: @LingamurthyCS, "Anything else must stay intact", so yes,  if there are other children - they should stay; anything within e3 is removed.  The accepted answer below takes care of that, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this can work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e2[e3]">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <e3 a="{@a}" b="{@b}" e="e"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e3"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It removes all existing `e3` elements and - for any `e2` element that contains at least one `e3` child element - adds a new `e3` element, copying the `@a` and `@b` attributes from the parent `e2` and adding a new `@e` attribute. Everything else is copied *as is*.